# Why multiple entries of libc and ld present in virtual address space

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, paging, memory-mapping

Following is one of the virtual address space of one process

```
004f3000-004f6000 r--p 000ad000 b3:02 24         /bin/bash.bash
004f6000-004fb000 rw-p 000b0000 b3:02 24         /bin/bash.bash
004fb000-00504000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
019e0000-025fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b6db4000-b6e91000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 20947      /lib/libc-2.29.so
b6e91000-b6ea0000 ---p 000dd000 b3:02 20947      /lib/libc-2.29.so
b6ea0000-b6ea2000 r--p 000dc000 b3:02 20947      /lib/libc-2.29.so
b6ea2000-b6ea4000 rw-p 000de000 b3:02 20947      /lib/libc-2.29.so
b6ea4000-b6ea6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6ea6000-b6ea8000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 21518      /lib/libdl-2.29.so
b6ea8000-b6eb7000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 21518      /lib/libdl-2.29.so
b6eb7000-b6eb8000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 21518      /lib/libdl-2.29.so
b6eb8000-b6eb9000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 21518      /lib/libdl-2.29.so
b6eb9000-b6ed1000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 20951      /lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
b6ed1000-b6ee1000 ---p 00018000 b3:02 20951      /lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
b6ee1000-b6ee3000 r--p 00018000 b3:02 20951      /lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
b6ee3000-b6ee4000 rw-p 0001a000 b3:02 20951      /lib/libtinfo.so.5.9
b6ee4000-b6efc000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 21510      /lib/ld-2.29.so
b6f0a000-b6f0c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6f0c000-b6f0d000 r--p 00018000 b3:02 21510      /lib/ld-2.29.so
b6f0d000-b6f0e000 rw-p 00019000 b3:02 21510      /lib/ld-2.29.so
bed0f000-bed30000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
bef12000-bef13000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

Why we have multiple entries of .so and bash in Virtual address space

Comment: Look at the offset field - these mappings are different regions of the file being mapped with different permissions.  Some segments of the file are code, others are data that may or may not be writable, etc.

Comment: so: code, static data (loaded from file), zero data, other data (not in file).